# Why is Error Code 429 appearing for sending notifications

Tags: notifications, actions-on-google, http-status-code-429

I have made an actions on google app for sending notifications during an event.The problem is sometimes the post request to send notifications is not completed and error 429 is shown as status code. Why is it happening? What if I want to send notification to a 1000 users at once. How should I do it? Can someone please help me? I need the solution as fast as possible. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP 429 error is ["Too many requests"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/429). This error typically occurs when you make too many API requests at a given time, exceeding quota.

If you are running into quota issues, you may want to update your notification logic to queue each request with a short delay.

You may also want to read the [Best practices and limits documentation](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/updates/best-practices-limits) for push notifications.

> Up to 10 notifications per user per day.
>
> Up to 1 notification per user per minute.